# Apache HttpClient 4.3 on Android 4.4

Tags: android, apache, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

Has anyone gotten Apache HttpClient 4.3 working on Android 4.4?  No mater what order I export the apache jars in eclipse the device uses the version of Apache HttpClient that comes with the Android SDK.

Comment: you can't use jars ... you have to take a source(of HttpClient library), rename packagename in the source, build to jar or add as project dependency

Comment: This link http://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/ may help you. It shows how to repackage the httpclient lib

Comment: I used this solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be an official [re-spin of Apache HttpClient 4.3](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient-android/trunk/) at some point. In the meantime there is not much one can do about the problem other then repackaging the stock HttpClient with a different namespace.

Comment: You can find the official project here: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html and get it from maven repository: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-android

Comment: New port is located here, it;s much easier to use then 4.3: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/android-port.html

Answer (score 0):

This is the gradle for the Apache HttpClient made for Android:

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
```